# I need to hide a key in nested json output in fastapi

Tags: fastapi

I am fetching data from postgresql and grouping the data by  pay date and username. In the json output I need to remove the pay date key...

```
            for result in results:
                

                if user_name not in user_comm_data:
                    user_comm_data[user_name] = {
                        "User_Name":user_name,
                        "Total_Commission_Amount": 0,
                        "Total_Designer_Error": 0,
                        "Pay_Dates":{},
                        
                    }
                
                if pay_date not in user_comm_data[user_name]["Pay_Dates"]:
                    user_comm_data[user_name]["Pay_Dates"][pay_date] = {
                        "Pay_Date" : pay_date,
                        "Orders":[]
                    }

                user_comm_data[user_name]["Pay_Dates"][pay_date]["Orders"].append({
                    "Commission_Amount": comm_amount,
                    "Order_Number": order_number,
                    "Amount_Debited": amount_debited
                })

                if comm_amount is not None:
                    user_comm_data[user_name]["Total_Commission_Amount"] += comm_amount
                if designer_err is not None:
                    user_comm_data[user_name]["Total_Designer_Error"] += designer_err

            adminData.extend(user_comm_data.values())

        return adminData
```

I am returning a json output where I don't want the date as key... Kindly help me to remove the pay date key as I am new to fast api...

```
{
    "User_Name": "Ashley Souder",
    "Total_Commission_Amount": 3879.55,
    "Total_Designer_Error": 0,
    "Pay_Dates": {
      "2022-11-04": {
        "Pay_Date": "2022-11-04",
        "Orders": [
          {
            "Commission_Amount": 125.95,
            "Order_Number": "00188989",
            "Amount_Debited": null
          },
          {
            "Commission_Amount": 1295.35,
            "Order_Number": "00188514",
            "Amount_Debited": null
          }
        ]
      },
      

... I need to remove "2022-11-04": type of keys from my output
```

Comment: What do you mean by remove? Should the entire value attached to that key be removed?  If so, shouldn't all children of `Pay_Dates` be removed?  If the value should not be removed how should it be represented in the result?

Comment: The functionality must remain the same, but I need output like this {
    "User_Name": "Ashley Souder",
    "Total_Commission_Amount": 3879.55,
    "Total_Designer_Error": 0,
    "Pay_Dates": {
      {
        "Pay_Date": "2022-11-04",
        "Orders": [
          {
            "Commission_Amount": 125.95,
            "Order_Number": "00188989",
            "Amount_Debited": null
          },
          {
            "Commission_Amount": 1295.35,
            "Order_Number": "00188514",
            "Amount_Debited": null
          }
        ]
      },

Comment: Call `user["Pay_Dates"] = list(user["Pay_Dates").values())` on the data before you return it? Or if you have defined a response model with List as the type for the field, dropping the explicit list conversion should work.